# Project sync issues : Connection to the Internet denied. ('Permission denied: connect')

Tags: android, build.gradle

When i attempting to sync your project, it is showing the following error message: "**Connection to the Internet denied.** ('Permission denied: connect')".

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this error message by adding the system property -`Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to your `gradle.properties` file in 
Android Studio as follows:

**Step1:** Open your **`gradle.properties`** file in Android Studio.

**Step2:** Add the following line to the file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

> **Note:** if you have already added other Gradle JVM arguments to your
>   gradle.properties file, you can add this property to the same line as
>   shown in the following example:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

**Step3:** Restart **Android Studio** for your changes to take effect.

**Step4:** Click **Sync Project with Gradle Files**(File > Sync Project with Gradle Files) to sync your project.

Answer (score 0):

Its a issue by window firewall, please turn off your window firewall.